# \fontseries{b} does not work in math mode

Tags: font-encodings, boldmath

The file is typeset in LaTeX, encoding T2A:

```
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
```

Everything works perfect, excepting bold in some formulae. I tried `\mathbf`, but it gives bold non-italic, whereas combining `\mathbf` and `\mathit` gives standard series. I tried `\fontseries{b}` which worked in the case of `fontenc{LCY}`, but now it works in the text mode only:

```
$\fontseries{b}\selectfont ff$ \fontseries{b}$gg$ \fontseries{b}\selectfont hh
```

gives standard ff and gg, and bold hh. Series `bx` has been tried as well.

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Comment: `\selectfont` and related commands have never worked in math mode. You probably want `\bm` (needs `\usepackage{bm}`).

Comment: egreg , thanks for clarification. My low reputation (I'm rather new here) doesn't allow to mark your comment by plus.

Answer (score 1):

Font selection commands such as `\fontseries` and `\selectfont` don't change fonts in math mode.

Also math alphabet selection commands such as `\mathbf` and `\mathit` don't “accumulate”: if you do `\mathbf{\mathit{x}}` you get the same as `\mathit{x}` and `\mathit{\mathbf{x}}` is the same as `\mathbf{x}`.

What you need is `\bm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$x+\mathit{x}+\mathbf{x}+\bm{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `T2A` should not be used if the document is in English and Greek, as it is an encoding for languages using the Cyrillic script.